# Booting problem with windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7

I have 2 hard drives. One of 500GB and other of 20GB. On 20 GB hard drive i had installed ubuntu 12.04 and on 500GB hard drive i had win xp. But today i installed win 7 on 500GB hard drive. But now i can not see that previous boot loader. By default win 7 starts. Even i tried changing order of Hard drives in "Boot Disk Priorities". But when i select that one hard drive computer doesn't start. And when i give priority to other hard drive win 7 starts by default. Also in win 7, in "MY COMPUTER" i can not see 2 partitions, as those i had assigned previously for ubuntu 12.04. But as i can boot through ubuntu 12.04, i can not access this 2 partitions

How to overcome the problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see ext4 partitions within windows 7 by default. You can try installing a bootloader entry for ubuntu in windows using command prompt or using a free tool like EasyBCD which provides you a clear gui. Add a new entry for Ubuntu in windows using EasyBCD and set bootloader as grub 2. Then you will get a new entry for ubuntu in windows boot manager list. I can give this answer as a help but I am lack of knowlege to tell you much technical details.

EasyBCD for windows : http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml